# How to best improve this piece of code in a try and catch block?

Tags: c#, specflow

I have this try and catch block statement within my specflow step definition file, more precisely in the When method where it has to validate some data coming through from a string, as shown below:

```
[When(@"this part is used to validate some parameters passing from a table into the source")]
public void WhenTheParamsArePassedThroughValidateTheSourceString(Table table)
{
    dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
    //validate
    try
    {
        if (source.Contains((string)data.A) && source.Contains((string)data.B)
            && source.Contains((string)data.C) && source.Contains((string)data.D)
            && source.Contains((string)data.E)
            && source.Contains((string)data.F)==false) //still nothing happens here
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
    catch
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }

}
```

I have 2 doubts about this, one the try isn't even working because when I put the first Assert as false, it never goes in the catch and 2nd, is there a better method of multiple if statements because it obviously doesn't recognise these, e.g. if I modify part of the string which doesn't contain F, then again nothing goes to catch block?  Am I missing something?

UPDATED WITH CODE AND SOURCE STRING:
When the data comes from this table

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| amazing | coders | are | very | hard | to | find |

```
string source = "amazing coders are very hard to find";
```

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the `try` isn't working. It's far more likely that the condition in the `if` statement is false, so the `Assert` isn't hit. It's impossible to tell why without information about `source` and `data`.

Comment: Just updated the feature file table and added a string, if you notice there is no G finding column if statement but this shouldn't matter.

Comment: It looks like you want an `else`, either instead of or in addition to the `catch`.  Even better, pass the condition as the parameter of `Assert.IsTrue()`.  Asserting on a constant is pretty useless, the preferred way to write `Assert.IsTrue(false)` is `Assert.Fail()`

Comment: Your code should be written as `Assert.IsTrue(source.Contains(A))` and so on then `Assert.IsFalse(source.Contains(F))`.  That way the test runner will pinpoint what went wrong.

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure why you're using a `try`/`catch` block at all. If an assertion fails, why wouldn't you want it to flow up to the test runner?

Comment: Great the aserts work like a charm, and even pinpoints the the errors. Perfect!